# Laravel nested array sorting by first value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting

while developing Laravel app I stuck on one problem with array sorting. At the beginning, I used partition problem to split my array into equal chunks by time, but now I have a problem sorting by the id of the array.

My array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(4)  <----- this is value i need to sort by
      [1]=>
      int(15)
      [2]=>
      string(64) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(6)
      [1]=>
      int(10)
      [2]=>
      string(64) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
      [1]=>
      int(8)
      [2]=>
      string(85) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(3)
      [1]=>
      int(14)
      [2]=>
      string(158) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(5)
      [1]=>
      int(12)
      [2]=>
      string(158) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(7)
      [2]=>
      string(55) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
  }
}
```

I need to sort by the first value of each array, so called my id.

Output I need:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(15)
      [2]=>
      string(64) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
      [1]=>
      int(10)
      [2]=>
      string(64) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(3)
      [1]=>
      int(8)
      [2]=>
      string(85) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(4)
      [1]=>
      int(14)
      [2]=>
      string(158) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(5)
      [1]=>
      int(12)
      [2]=>
      string(158) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      int(6)
      [1]=>
      int(7)
      [2]=>
      string(55) "text..."
      [3]=>
      string(6) "650008"
      [4]=>
      string(13) "NP08KDT"
      [5]=>
      int(48)
      [6]=>
      string(6) "456467"
      [7]=>
      int(33)
    }
  }
}
```

maybe any of you guys have any solutions how i could solve this problem, so far i tried a lot of sorting functions, none of them seems to work properly for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may not be the best way to do this, but you can try something like this.

```
$tempArray = array();
$sortedArray = array();

foreach ($yourArray as $key1 => $arr){// create 2D array

    foreach ($arr as $key2 => $arr2){
        $tempArray[] = $arr2;        
    }

}

foreach ($tempArray as $keyTemp => $tempElem){

    $sortingArray[] = $tempElem[0];//get array value you need to sort

}    
asort($sortingArray);// sort array maintaining the key

foreach ($sortingArray as $keySort => $sortElem){//loop through sorted array to push elements to a new array
    $sortedArray[] = $tempArray[$keySort];
}

print_r($sortedArray);
```

Comment: Almost working! :) just it sorts each array, i need that it would be ascending from 1 to 6 through both of those arrays. I hope you understood what i meant :)

Comment: i thought u needed each array to sort separately (as you have mentioned in the output of your question). changed my answer, please check the edit

Comment: ohh, probably i'm really bad at explaining things, hmm, how to say, the idea here is working really well, but let's say i have those two arrays and now their id's is very random, so what i need is that those both arrays would be ascending, example: array1 - 1, 2, 3; array2 - 4, 5, 6; I hope now it's more clear, really thanks for your effort, will mark your answer as solved for it :)

Comment: think i got the idea now. you may need to do some workaround for that. one way is that you can use `array_chunk` for `$sortedArray`. any way, give it a try and thank you for selecting this as the correct answer :)